# getting errors when trying to upgrade system

Tags: system-installation, dpkg

I was trying to follow instructions to for the problem of dpkg interrupting, manually recover

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
reading files list for package 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: thanks zanna, i couldnt figure out how to edit it in that manner.

Comment: Frequent input/output error usually means a failing (or failed) disk, disk controller, or motherboard. If possible, move the disk to a different system and preserve any data that you value to a more trustworthy media. Usually, the process of copying from the suspect drive will allow you to narrow the selection of which hardware is bad.

Comment: yea whenever i was trying to copy a file greater than 1gb it used to give me the input/output splicing error